# How can I backdate a timestamp by one day?

Tags: org-mode

In org mode, I'm usually lazy and forget to check off todo items on the day of. Instead, I remember the next day, and then have to mark an item as done, and then edit the timestamp so that it's for the previous day. But there must be an easier way. Is there already a function for this? If not, how would I go about writing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `org-todo-yesterday` and `org-agenda-todo-yesterday`.

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain what to do with these commands.